# Interpretation of Tensor of Unit Vectors

Tags: tensors

Today i got to know the folloeing expression 
$$(e_i-e_j) \otimes (e_i-e_j)$$
for $i,j \in \{ 1, \dots, n \}$ and where $e_i $ denotes the ith unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. However i cannot figure out how to interpret this. My guess is that it could be a tensor and wikipedia approves. However i could not find out how to caclulate the above expression.

EDIT: This appeared in a sum of the form 
$$K = \sum_{j = 2}^n \sum_{i = 1}^{j-1} \alpha_{ij}(e_i-e_j) \otimes (e_i-e_j)$$
for constants $\alpha_{i,j}$ and it is multiplied by a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. $Kv$ is calculated.

Comment: Is there an implicit summation in the expression?  Otherwise it can't be "calculated" any further—it is what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, here $x\otimes y$ denotes the rank-one operator
$$
(x\otimes y)\,v=\langle v,y\rangle\,x. 
$$

I have never been in love with this notation, but have recently started to come to grips with it. While I don't know for certain, it seems to come from the natural embedding $H\otimes H^*\hookrightarrow L^2(H)$ given by 
$$
\sum_j x_j\otimes f_j\longmapsto \sum_j x_j f_j,
$$
where $F(H)$ denotes the set of Hilbert-Schmidt operators. The embedding above turns out to be an isometric isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you! This aligns perfectly well with the rest of the calculation.